# Matlab dynamic plot axis

Tags: matlab, axis, figure

At the moment I'm plotting two points in a grid and I'm using the `xlim` and `ylim` to force the scale of my plot, like this

[image]

but I'd like to have a plot that changes dynamically the axis depending on where is my target. This because my red point might go above `xlim` and `ylim` or way below of it, like these two cases.

[image]
[image]

In the first one, the point is outside the window and therefore I cannot see it, while in the other case, the point is close to the origin of the plot and I'd like to see it more closely, like if I zoom in.
For now I'm using

```
plot(x,y,'.','MarkerSize',20,'Color','r');
xlim([-a a]);
ylim([-a a]);
```

I think that to do what I need, I should use `x,y` somehow instead of `a` or a combination of the two in order to have a more dynamic range depending on the dimension of `x,y`.
Is there any other easier and faster way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use axis handles and change the `XData` and `YData` properties to dynamically change axis limits. Consider the following sample code that plots a random data point and dynamically updates the axis limits,

```
h = figure;
% get axis handle
ax = gca(h);
set(ax, {'XLim', 'YLim'}, {[-1 1], [-1 1]});

XY = [];

for i = 1:100
    % generate random data point
    xy = 2*randn(1, 2);
    XY = cat(1, XY, xy);

    % get min and max values of points so far
    minVals = min(XY, [], 1);
    maxVals = max(XY, [], 1);

    % plot the data point
    scatter(xy(1), xy(2), 'b*');
    hold on;

    % update the axis limits dynamically
    set(ax, {'XLim', 'YLim'}, {[minVals(1)-1 maxVals(1)+1], [minVals(2)-1 maxVals(2)+1]});
    % pause so that you can see the plot update
    pause(0.5);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`axis tight`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-mode) command. According to the documentation, what it does is

> *Fit the axes box tightly around the data by setting the axis limits equal to the range of the data.*
>
> ...
>
> *The limits automatically update to incorporate new data added to the axes. To keep the limits from changing when using `hold on`, use `axis tight manual`.*

Here's a demonstration:

```
y = randi(21,10,1)-11;
figure(); hP = plot(NaN(10,1),NaN(10,1),'-o'); axis tight; grid minor;
for ind1 = 1:numel(x)
  hP.XData(ind1) = x(ind1);
  hP.YData(ind1) = y(ind1);
  pause(0.5);
end
```

Notice how the axis limits change automatically:

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: Is it also possible to use `axis tight` + something? Because with `axis tight` the maximum value in my plot overlaps with the border of my graph

Comment: That won't make them `tight` :) I can't think of a good way to do it, but you can try adding `hAx.XLim = hAx.XLim*1.1; hAx.YLim = hAx.YLim*1.1;` after the plot (assuming `hAx` is the axes' handle).